# MPV linux player map sound to specific 7.1 sound card channel

Tags: linux, alsa, mpv, surround

i have a 7.1 usb sound card connected to a debian system. MPV version is 0.35
I have a multiroom audio setup, with one stereo aplifier per room. The sound card should feed the rooms individually.

Alsa speaker test does work, with s number I can switch through the loudspeakers.

`speaker-test -Dplug:surround71:ICUSBAUDIO7D -c8 -s8`

Now I want to route the stereo mp3 signal to a soundcard output. Whatever I tried, it is only playing front left and front right. Also tried with --af=channelmapl=map=... , but no success.

```
mpv --no-video --audio-device=alsa/surround71:CARD=ICUSBAUDIO7D,DEV=0 --audio-channels=bl,br  --alsa-ignore-chmap *
```

mpv --no-video --audio-device=alsa/surround71:CARD=ICUSBAUDIO7D,DEV=0 --audio-channels=bl,br  --alsa-ignore-chmap *

should play on the right channel